# How to make translation in cocos2D

Tags: objective-c, animation, cocos2d-iphone, translate-animation

and merry Christmas !

My question  is about cocos2D, and how to do a translation in cocos2D. In "classic" objective C, I would have done :

```
myAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x"];
myAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
myAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:200.0f];
myAnimation.duration = t;
myAnimation.repeatCount = 1;
[myUIImageView.layer addAnimation:myAnimation forKey:@"myAnimation"];
```

But i don't find the equivalent when I tried to make an action :

```
id action = [CC… ?];
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be looking for members of the CCAction class.

For example, CCMoveTo will move a CCNode from its current position to a new position over a period of time.  CCMoveBy will move a CCNode by a certain amount (relative).  etc.

[See this reference](http://learn-cocos2d-by-example.blogspot.com/2013/01/working-with-ccaction.html) (and search google for "Cocos2d CCAction", there are lots of references).

Was this helpful?

Comment: Looks to be helpful =) Thanks !

Comment: Odd...a vote down on an accepted answer, after the answer was accepted, and without a comment to even explain why...curious.

Answer (score 0):

use a CCMoveTo (for displacement to an absolute x,y) or CCMoveBy for a relative movement from current position at the moment when the animation starts.